# Simple Card Flip And Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zooming, flip

My goal is to take three images of cards and make them interactive. The user should be able to "pickup" a card which is a CSS zoom started by hover and then flip the image, while it's zoomed, with a javascript function that is called "switchImg".

The Javascript:

```
function switchImg1() {
if ($('#one').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#one').css('display', 'inline');
    $('#two').css('display', 'none');
} else {
    $('#one').css('display', 'none');
    $('#two').css('display', 'inline');
}
}

function switchImg2() {
if ($('#three').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#three').css('display', 'inline');
    $('#four').css('display', 'none');
} else {
    $('#three').css('display', 'none');
    $('#four').css('display', 'inline');
}
}

function switchImg3() {
if ($('#five').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#five').css('display', 'inline');
    $('#six').css('display', 'none');
} else {
    $('#five').css('display', 'none');
    $('#six').css('display', 'inline');
}
}
```

The CSS:

```
#container {
float:left;
position:relative;
margin:auto 0;
width:100%;
}
#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six {
z-index:10;
-webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
#one:hover, #two:hover, #three:hover, #four:hover, #five:hover, #six:hover {
transform: scale(2);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<!-- Card One -->
<img id="one" style="cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switchImg1()" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-mFYEpMXprYY/VEbJwkJXJaI/AAAAAAAALp4/9GduJ-BGvFk/s524/example-a.jpg" alt="A" />
<img id="two" style="display:none; cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switchImg1()" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ElSRd-aC0lI/VEbJ0fwy4rI/AAAAAAAALqQ/kVli8v9s-Cw/s524/example-b.jpg" alt="B" />
<!-- Card Two -->
<img id="three" style="cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switchImg2()" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-XfqG26ltMm4/VEbJ0egpaUI/AAAAAAAALqM/Q3eL6avhUJQ/s524/example-c.jpg" alt="C" />
<img id="four" style="display:none; cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switchImg2()" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-KieQ3h-5Lp8/VEbJ0fjArLI/AAAAAAAALqI/bYxzgCuxQxo/s524/example-d.jpg" alt="D" />
<!-- Card Three -->
<img id="five" style="cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switchImg3()" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-aa_TydW4QbA/VEbKcwU_foI/AAAAAAAALqY/_fEGuyjnb5c/s524/example-e.jpg" alt="E" />
<img id="six" style="display:none; cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switch3Img()" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_wQu4iMCRaY/VEbK0snmzAI/AAAAAAAALqg/d1F76OXqE7U/s524/example-f.jpg" alt="F" />
</div>
```

My Javascript code is probably redundant (3 functions for 3 cards doing the same thing) but the main issue is that after the user zooms the card and then tries to flip it - the image re-sizes down to it's starting size, then re-zooms.

Is there a way to clean up my code or is there a better way to handle this task? There is an identical example up on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GargantuanMedia/sdq444we/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that when one of the div card is hidden, it will not get `:hover`ed. You can probably do this with jQuery animation but I'm not sure how to. What I did was that I [improved your switchImg() function.](http://jsfiddle.net/sdq444we/4/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use javascript. You can do this all with CSS these days.

To handle the hoverstate correctly you need to surround the 2 images with 1 div and make his hover state leading in your css.

Using *display: none* makes it impossible to animate an element. There is another trick to hide elements which comes in handy for you. You can use the *backface-visibility: hidden* css property to give elements just 1 face instead of the default of 2 when you rotate it 180 degrees.

That in combination with *transform: rotateX()* gives you this jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/odqvozwL/

EDIT: I've further improved my answer. I cleaned up some html markup, added a little script, imagined what you want and added that to the example. Here is the jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7sp5qtmh/

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
}
.card {
    width: 20%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.card > img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: .75s ease;
    -moz-transition: .75s ease
    -o-transition: .75 ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card > img:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.card.turned {
    z-index: 2;
}

.card:hover {
    z-index: 3;    
}

/* Hover states */
.card:hover > img {
    transform: scale(2);
}
.card:hover > img:nth-child(2) {
    transform: scale(2) rotateX(180deg);
}

/* Clicked states */
.card.turned > img:nth-child(1) {
    transform: scale(1) rotateX(-180deg);
}
.card.turned > img:nth-child(2) {
    transform: scale(1);
}
.card.turned:hover > img:nth-child(1) {
    transform: scale(2) rotateX(-180deg);
}
.card.turned:hover > img:nth-child(2) {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- Card One -->
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-mFYEpMXprYY/VEbJwkJXJaI/AAAAAAAALp4/9GduJ-BGvFk/s524/example-a.jpg" alt="A" />
        <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ElSRd-aC0lI/VEbJ0fwy4rI/AAAAAAAALqQ/kVli8v9s-Cw/s524/example-b.jpg" alt="B" />
    </div>
        <!-- Card Two -->
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-XfqG26ltMm4/VEbJ0egpaUI/AAAAAAAALqM/Q3eL6avhUJQ/s524/example-c.jpg" alt="C" />
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-KieQ3h-5Lp8/VEbJ0fjArLI/AAAAAAAALqI/bYxzgCuxQxo/s524/example-d.jpg" alt="D" />
    </div>
    <!-- Card Three -->
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-aa_TydW4QbA/VEbKcwU_foI/AAAAAAAALqY/_fEGuyjnb5c/s524/example-e.jpg" alt="E" />
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_wQu4iMCRaY/VEbK0snmzAI/AAAAAAAALqg/d1F76OXqE7U/s524/example-f.jpg" alt="F" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
function turn(){
    //Return turned cards back to their original position
    //$('.card').removeClass('turned');

    //Turn this card
    if(!$(this).hasClass('turned')){
        $(this).addClass('turned')
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('turned')
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('ready');
    $('.card').click(turn);
});
```

You can still experiment further with the 3D effect by adding a perspective property. But this should be what you want.

Comment: This is an interesting possible solution. I like how you have added a rotateX to the zoom action but this "flip" needs to occur separately from the zoom. Also, I notice that the "A" card is jumping most of the time on hover in a way that the other cards are not.

Comment: I think it looks like the A is moving into the other direction because the other cards letters are vertical symmatrical. You can see that the A is moving the wrong way for some reason.

Comment: I've improved my answer to what I think what you want. I misreaded your first post about the click functionaliteit last night. I've also rotated the A-card the other way around. Let me know if the rotation of the A-card looks correct this way. I'm curious because I can't really see the difference anymore after looking at for a few minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with was a very basic one. The transition was removed to stop the gap that was happening between the front image/back images. The images are now preloading in order to make the flip seem instantaneous.

CSS

```
#preload { 
display: none; 
}

#container-a {
float:left;
position:relative;
margin:auto 0;
width:100%;
}

#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six {
z-index:10;
}

#one:hover, #two:hover, #three:hover, #four:hover, #five:hover, #six:hover {
transform: scale(2);
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
}
```

JS

```
function switchImg(a,b) {
$('#'+a).css('display', 'none');
$('#'+b).css('display', 'inline');
```

}

HTML

```
<div id="preload">
<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-mFYEpMXprYY/VEbJwkJXJaI/AAAAAAAALp4/9GduJ-BGvFk/s524/example-a.jpg" width="1" height="1" alt="A" />
<img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ElSRd-aC0lI/VEbJ0fwy4rI/AAAAAAAALqQ/kVli8v9s-Cw/s524/example-b.jpg" width="1" height="1" alt="B" />
<img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-XfqG26ltMm4/VEbJ0egpaUI/AAAAAAAALqM/Q3eL6avhUJQ/s524/example-c.jpg" width="1" height="1" alt="C" />
<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-KieQ3h-5Lp8/VEbJ0fjArLI/AAAAAAAALqI/bYxzgCuxQxo/s524/example-d.jpg" width="1" height="1" alt="D" />
<img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-aa_TydW4QbA/VEbKcwU_foI/AAAAAAAALqY/_fEGuyjnb5c/s524/example-e.jpg" width="1" height="1" alt="E" />
<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-eLsaIjwvgWU/VEYZZaKkPVI/AAAAAAAALps/9eeXxPJ55yE/s524/card-back-c.jpg" width="1" height="1" alt="F" />
</div>
<div id="container-a">
<!-- Card One -->
<img id="one" style="cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switchImg('one','two')" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-mFYEpMXprYY/VEbJwkJXJaI/AAAAAAAALp4/9GduJ-BGvFk/s524/example-a.jpg" alt="A" />
<img id="two" style="display:none; cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switchImg('two','one')" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ElSRd-aC0lI/VEbJ0fwy4rI/AAAAAAAALqQ/kVli8v9s-Cw/s524/example-b.jpg" alt="B" />
<!-- Card Two -->
<img id="three" style="cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switchImg('three','four')" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-XfqG26ltMm4/VEbJ0egpaUI/AAAAAAAALqM/Q3eL6avhUJQ/s524/example-c.jpg" alt="C" />
<img id="four" style="display:none; cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switchImg('four','three')" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-KieQ3h-5Lp8/VEbJ0fjArLI/AAAAAAAALqI/bYxzgCuxQxo/s524/example-d.jpg" alt="D" />
<!-- Card Three -->
<img id="five" style="cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switchImg('five','six')" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-aa_TydW4QbA/VEbKcwU_foI/AAAAAAAALqY/_fEGuyjnb5c/s524/example-e.jpg" alt="E" />
<img id="six" style="display:none; cursor:pointer; width:30%;" onclick="switchImg('six','five')" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_wQu4iMCRaY/VEbK0snmzAI/AAAAAAAALqg/d1F76OXqE7U/s524/example-f.jpg" alt="F" />
</div>
```

[Charly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3961141/charly) made a significant contribution to this short project. A working example of this version is up at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GargantuanMedia/rkLjo2f5/3/).

In the near future, I will develop a more realistic version using the example from [Wezelkrozum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1375229/wezelkrozum) with rotateY in perspective with toggling classes in a list.

Comment: Good luck! I'll further update my answer with a clickable rotation animation.